# RuntimeError: Result vector from pandas_udf was not the required length: expected 2, got 1

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use `pandas_udf`.

I have my Spark DataFrame, in which I have an Array Column of Struct:

```
root
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = true)
```

What I would like to do is running my pandas_udf over the `values` Column and for each record (which means for each array) returning a value based on a defined logic.

When in my data-source I have more than one record with the Column `values` containing an empty array I get this error:

```
line 89, in verify_result_length "expected %d, got %d" % (len(a[0]), len(result)))

RuntimeError: Result vector from pandas_udf was not the required length: expected 2, got 1
```

Searching on Google I found the source code here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/worker.py

On the other hand if I have only one record with an empty array the process ends without any issue. Filtering in Spark the records with empty arrays doesn't help (FYI `.filter("size(values) != 0")` ), it leads to the same behaviour.

But I can't understand why I'm getting this error and what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

**CODE**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

udf = f.pandas_udf(udf_function, returnType="float")
df.withColumn("newColumn",
             f.when(f.size(f.col("values")) == 0, 0)\
             .otherwise(udf(f.col("values.x"), f.col("values.y"))))

def udf_function(x_array, y_array, Window=20):
   xy = []
   data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x_array.tolist()[0], 'y': y_array.tolist()[0]})

   x = data['x'].rolling(int(Window / 2), center=True, min_periods=1).sum()
   y = data['y'].rolling(int(Window / 2), center=True, min_periods=1).sum()

   for index in range(len(x)):
       xy.append(np.sqrt(x[index] ** 2 + y[index] ** 2))

   if not xy:
       result = 0
   else:
       result = max(xy)

   return pd.Series(result)
```

**RECORDS**:

```
{
  "values": []
}

{
  "values": []
}

{
  "values": [
    {
      "x": -0.638,
      "y": 0.879,
    },
    {
      "x": -0.616,
      "y": 0.809,
    },
    {
      "x": -0.936,
      "y": 0.762,
    }]
}
```

P.S. even if with the `f.when(f.size(f.col("values")) == 0, 0).otherwise(udf() )` condition is supposed to filter out the records with empty arrays (or at least in case of empty array the udf function is not supposed to be called), it looks like that anyway the udf function processes these records! D: Which is very weird to me

**FURTHER CONTEXT**:

the exception was raised when I used about 15 or more input files, there is no relationship with the use of records with empty arrays. It is anyway a weird exception, because with the observed behaviour I was expecting something like "JavaOutOfMemory Exception", but the reported exception doesn't help me so much to understand the real problem.

In the meanwhile I came back using the more stables RDD rather than pandas_udf.

Comment: Can you provide some dummy data and your udf to replicate the issue?

Comment: @pansen edited! I hope it helps to reproduce it (it's up to you how to read the json in Spark), let me know if you need something else or you managed to reproduce the situation. You can easily increase or decrease the number of records with empty array